# A POINTER DECLARED IN CLASS NOT DECLARED IN THIS SCOPE

Tags: c++

I am kind a beginner to c++ and i dont really understand much about pointers.
There is an error in the code below. Soldier is a class in my program. The error states that 'targetsoldier was not declared in this scope'.

```
void level::battle(soldier *soldier, int targetx, int targety)
{
int x, y;
int enemyarmy;
soldier->getposition(x, y);

soldier *targetsoldier = getsoldier(targetx, targety);//THE ERROR OCCURS IN 
THIS LINE
if(targetsoldier == nullptr){
    return;
}
enemyarmy = targetsoldier->getarmy();
if(enemyarmy == soldier->getarmy()){
    return;
}

int result = targetsoldier->takedamage(soldier->attack());
if(result ==1){
    for(int h=0; h < _armies[enemyarmy].size(); h++){
        if(_armies[enemyarmy][h] == targetsoldier) {
           _armies[enemyarmy][h] = _armies[enemyarmy].back();
           _armies[enemyarmy].pop_back();
           delete *targetsoldier;
           settile(targetx, targety, ' ', nullptr);
           break;
        }
    }


 }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to remove all caps in the title and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `soldier` is an instance or a type? `soldier->getposition(x,y)` suggests the first while `soldier* targetsoldier;` suggests the second. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @user463035818 It's both, depending on scope. See the parameter `soldier *soldier`

Comment: Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to add more details (besides the MCVE), like the *actual* error, in full and complete and copy-pasted as text. The actual error contains information that we need to be able to help you properly.

Comment: Beginners are well advised not to use pointers.

Comment: @Angew yeah just spotted it. Its not a bug but a feature, though imho being able to do that does more harm than good

Comment: I dont think THE COMPILER SCREAMS AT YOU THOUGH.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function has a parameter named `soldier`; the name of that parameter then hides the name of the class `soldier` when it's in scope (i.e. inside the function). There are two possible solutions:

1. The sane one: rename the parameter (or the class)
2. The alternative: use `class soldier` instead of just `solider` to refer to the type when the parameter is in scope.